# Spring3.1+Hibernate4.1.2+GlassFish3.1.2 : JTA : no transaction is in progress

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, jta

I'm using Spring3.1, Hibernate(JPA) 4.1.2, GlassFish 3.1.2.

I have already successed to access to DB via JPA and JNDI datasource,
but when I tried to insert data to DB, met the problem below.

```
[#|2012-05-02T21:19:55.714+0900|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:976)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
        at $Proxy227.flush(Unknown Source)
```

My source code is below.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
        <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
                <properties>
                        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
                        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
                        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory" />
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Spring config

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDataSource" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* x.y.z.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

Dao interface

```
package x.y.z;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface MyTableDao {

    @Transactional
    public void persist(MyTable myTable);

}
```

Dao implementation

```
package x.y.z;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class MyTableDaoImpl implements MyTableDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(MyTable myTable) {
        em.persist(myTable);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Please teach me what is wrong!

Comment: Please check if the transaction propogation has anything to do with it. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Answer (score 0):

Place the @Transactional annotation on the concrete persist method instead of the interface.